# Revoke SSL certificate

Tags: swisscomdev

I'm trying to revoke some SSL certificates for private routes from the developer console. Some of them were successfully revoked, but some others cannot be revoked:

> Revoking certificate for mydomain.com failed.
>
> A running revoke process
>   in init status exists for the domain 'mydomain.com'.

I waited for while and tried again, but I still can't revoke the certificates. I've been trying this since yesterday, waiting about 8h since the last time I tried.

How can I revoke these certificates ?

I saw on Swisscom Extensions API documentation that there's a request to do manually revoke a SSL certificate (https://api.lyra-836.appcloud.swisscom.com/api-doc/#!/Certification_Processes/put_custom_certifications_revoke), but how am I supposed to log in to get a token ?

Comment: I think it's them, not you. Open a support ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to various reasons the certification revoke process can fail and in some cases an automatic resolution is not possible. Please contact [Swisscom's Developer Support](https://developer.swisscom.com/support) and give them the ORG, SPACE and domain affected.

To interact with the API directly follow these [instructions to login](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/tutorial-go/set-up.html) and then use i.e. `cf curl -X GET /custom/accounts` to execute requests against the [Cloud Controller](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/concepts/architecture/cloud-controller.html).

Comment: That is what I did and they solved my issue. I didn't think to `cf curl` for the custom API. Thank you !